# C language - scanf more inputs but dont know how many inputs

Tags: c, scanf

I need help with `scanf`. I need to scan multiple inputs in the format "x y then another line x1 y1 another line x2 y2" but the last line needs to end with with scanf equal to line 1 (x,y) ...

Example

```
scanf("%lf %lf\n",%x,%y);
scanf("%lf %lf\n",%x1,%y2);
```

and more scanf until the last scanf is equal to the first scanf.
With these inputs I'll then need to calculate polygon.

Can someone help me with this? Thank you for help :)

Comment: What is the problem ? How do you plan to store the polygon ?

Comment: It should be `&x`, not `%x`.

Comment: It sounds like you need to write a loop. And you should probably be using arrays, not variables with names like `x1`, `x2`, etc.

Comment: 1st input in scanf is point A in polygon ... next inputs are others points in polygon until last points is same as point A ... and from these inputs i need to calculate contests of polygon and all pages of polygon

Answer (score 0):

Just add data that were read into the array. Then in while read data while current x and y does not match first x and y.

Comment: Yea but i dont have idea how to use array ... i never use it ... im using c in school for 2 monts only so its not that easy for me ... any idea to do it without array ?

Comment: You just can't do it without array because you don't know how many vertices will you obtain. Arrays are easy, just look https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm :)